# Point vm to OS installer when choosing install OS later in VMWare Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have installed vmware workstation.

I selected "install OS later" when I ran the wizard to create a new VM.

How can I now point the VM to an ISO file to run the installation for an OS? Would I have to paste the contents of the ISO to the virtual disk? Basically if I launch the VM with the option of installing an OS later, I get a black screen (like DOS).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

- Right-click on the VM
- Click **Settings**
- Click on **CD/DVD**
- Check option to **Use ISO image file**
- Browse to the ISO file and open it
- Make sure option to **Connect at power on** is checked
- Start the VM and it will boot from the virtual installer disc

[image]